# wp_update_user isn't instantly?

Tags: post-meta

I'm trying to update a user mail recieved by $_POST and use it instantly. It gets changed, however it outputs the old one. What is the way to do it?

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        wp_update_user( array('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => $_POST['email']) );
        get_currentuserinfo(); //just in case
}

echo '<p>You'll recieve a mail here: ' . $current_user->user_email . '</p>'; //outputs old mail
```

Maybe it has to be with the global $current_user var?

EDIT:

Chuncky fix,

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

$email = $current_user->user_email;

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
     wp_update_user( array('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => $_POST['email']) );
     $email = $_POST['email'];
}

echo '<p>You'll recieve a mail here: ' . $email . '</p>';
```

Comment: To update just the email use [`update_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta). Anyway, acording to the docs, `get_currentuserinfo()` should update the `$current_user` var. Anyway, if already have the data, you should check if the update was correct, and if it was, use the value in the `$_POST`

Comment: It outputs the old database value, I don't know why. Maybe something to be with the cache? The problem in using the $_POST  data directly is that it would only be used if it was set.

Comment: can you change the `wp_update_user`with `var_dump(wp_update_user( array('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => $_POST['email']) ))` The idea is to know if the update is working.

Comment: Yep. It's working. In fact, I see it refreshing Users admin page.

Comment: I made a provisional fix. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
            wp_update_user( array('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => $_POST['email']) );
            unset($current_user);
            get_currentuserinfo(); //just in case
    }

    echo '<p>You'll recieve a mail here: ' . $current_user->user_email . '</p>';
```

Now it should work, the problem was on the `get_currentuserinfo()` function, [because it checks if the variable is already set and is an instace of `WP_User`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L83), if it is, the function "aborts" (returns) and doesn't update the variable.